# match non existant records in first table to second table inner join

Tags: sql

How do I match records in first table that don't exist to records in second table on the inner join clause. For example, if I am inner joining based on office numbers but office number 90 does not exist in second table, but the closest office is 91 then how would I 'substitute' or make that match?

if office='90' then where in office in ('91')

Comment: You really need to provide sample input and output, because your question does not make sense.  It is not possible to "match records in [the] first table that don't exist . . .".  The records don't exist.

Comment: Yeah I have to agree that it sounds like you want a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an inner join. 

you can also in the 'on' clause use less strict criteria than EQUALS. You can do OR Statements in the ON structure.

SELECT * FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON (t1.aColumn = t2.aColumn OR t1.aColumn = t2.aColumn + 1)

I believe it depends on the DBMS that you're using on how liberal you can be on the ON clause

Comment: Are you dealing with numbers or strings?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a separate mapping table and join with that.  Something like this:

```
OfficeNumberMap
  - OfficeNumber
  - SubstituteOfficeNumber
```

So in that table you would have an entry for every "valid" office number mapping to itself, and entries for an "invalid" office number mapping to the substitute.

```
Office Number | SubstituteOfficeNumber
--------------+-----------------------
            80                      80  <- valid
            81                      81  <- valid
            90                      91  <- Invalid, so use 91 as alternate.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would think that finding the closest numeric match in a list would be something easily expressed in SQL.  And there is a way, although the exact syntax varies by database:

```
select ft.officenumber,
       (select OfficeNumber from SecondTable st order by abs(ft.OfficeNumber - st.OfficeNumber limit 1
       ) as MyBestGuess
from FirstTable ft
```

What this is doing is using a correlated subquery to look through the second table.  It is ordering all the results by the absolute value of the difference and then choosing the first value.

A couple comments. In any SQL engine I can think of, this will require a full table scan of SecondTable for every row of FirstTable.  Translation:  it is slow and will get much slower faster as the amount of data increases.

Second, this only works on numerical values.  I don't know what "close" means for character strings.

Third, `limit` is common syntax to get only the first row of output.  It works in most databases.  In SQL Server, you would use `select top 1` and in Oracle, you would use `where rownum = 1`.